Permission needed to update Asset
I am trying to update category ID for Template-based email type Content. But getting permission error when tryin to update via API. What permission is needed to update the content?


I figured it out. Below acccess to update the asset
Access:
Offline Access
Email:
Read, Write, Send
Documents and Images:
Read, Write
Saved Content:
Read, Write
